# I want generate XML file in a hierarchical form

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, hierarchy, for-xml-path

I have a table like this (Actually it contains more 6000 records)

```
IdIndustry   |   IndustryCode  |   IndustryName  |  ParentId
---------------------------------
1    |  IND    |   Industry  |   NULL
2    |  PHARM  |   Pharmacy  |   1
3    |  FIN    |   Finance   |   NULL
4    |  CFIN   |   Corporate |   3
5    |  CMRKT  |   Capital M |   4
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblIndustryCodes](
    [IdIndustry] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IndustryCode] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [IndustryName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblIndustryCodes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdIndustry] ASC)
```

Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO [tblIndustryCodes]
          ([IndustryCode]
          ,[IndustryName]
          ,[ParentId])
     VALUES
          ('IND','Industry',NULL),
          ('PHARM','Pharmacy',1),
          ('FIN','Finance',NULL),
          ('CFIN','Corporate Finance',3),
          ('CMRKT','Capital Markets',4)
```

And i want to generate a XML file like this(Simplified tree like structure)

```
<IND>
      <PHARM>
      </PHARM>
</IND>
<FIN>
      <CFIN>
            <CMRKT>
            </CMRKT>
      </CFIN>
<FIN>
```

<s>I don't want to use recursion as it would downgrade the performance dramatically as this table has more than 60000 records in table.</s>

I would be glad if i get the output in same format, since i will be using this output XML to send a request.

<s>And more importantly it will be dynamic in nature.</s>

Comment: Ok, i did some extra home work,and some how i came to know that it will be done through "sp_xml_preparedocument" procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this procedure not much sure about its efficiency as I am creating a temp table to get result

```
create procedure get_path as begin
  DECLARE @cnt INT
  DECLARE @n INT
  DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(id int, 
                indCode varchar(50), 
                indName varchar(100),
                parentId int,
                path varchar(500))

  insert @tmpTable 
          select [IdIndustry], [IndustryCode], [IndustryName], [ParentId],
          null from tbl

  select @cnt = count(*)  from @tmpTable where parentId is null
  update a set a.path = CONCAT(b.indName,'/',a.indName) from @tmpTable a, @tmpTable b where b.parentid is null and a.parentid = b.id
  select @n = count(*)  from @tmpTable where path is null
  while (@cnt < @n) begin
    update a set a.path = concat(b.path, '/', b.indName, '/', a.indName) from @tmpTable a, @tmpTable b where b.path is not null and a.parentid = b.id
    select @n = count(*) from @tmpTable where path is null
  end
  update @tmpTable set path = indName where parentid is null 
  select * from @tmpTable order by path
end
go
```

**Query 1**:

```
exec get_path
```

**Results**:

```
| ID | INDCODE |   INDNAME | PARENTID |                                  PATH |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |     FIN |   Finance |   (null) |                               Finance |
|  4 |    CFIN | Corporate |        3 |                     Finance/Corporate |
|  5 |   CMRKT | Capital M |        4 | Finance/Corporate/Corporate/Capital M |
|  1 |     IND |  Industry |   (null) |                              Industry |
|  2 |   PHARM |  Pharmacy |        1 |                     Industry/Pharmacy |
```

Hope this helps.....

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30cb6/1)**

Comment: Which language you are using for getting in language? but better first try if there is some problem post it will be glad to help...

Comment: What do you mean by max level ?

Comment: By level i mean child and parent(generation).

Comment: Sorry don't have that much time right now. Pl post whatever problem you are facing. Will try to solve during later part of day...