# Copy tree via SQL function

Tags: mysql

I want to copy a tree via a MySQL function. My table structure looks like this:

```
id|parent_id|name|position
1|0|rootnode|1
2|1|firstchild|1
3|1|secondchild|2
4|0|anotherroot|2
5|4|anotherchild|1
```

If I copy it it should look like this (remember: id is autoinc!) :

```
id|parent_id|name|position
6|0|rootnode|1
7|6|firstchild|1
8|6|secondchild|2
9|0|anotherroot|2
10|9|anotherchild|1
```

Is this possible? Are recursiv functions possible in MySQL? MySQL Version is 5.0.95

Best regards ...

Comment: Hope this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584013/how-to-find-the-hierarchy-path-for-a-tree-representation/15861254#15861254

Comment: Hi, I want to copy the whole tree. My problem is the regeneartion of  the autoincrement id's - so I lost the assignments.

Comment: Can you post some example...

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: I've edited my first post. I got no code example. If I use Delphi or PHP I manage this with a recursive function, but SQL - I don't know!

Comment: No, MySQL does not support recursive functions.  It does support recursive *procedures*, up to a recursion depth of 255, but they are disabled by default.  In general, MySQL is not well suited to this "adjacency list" model for hierarchical data; one is usually better to model the data using nested sets or a transitive closure table.

Comment: You can create a stored procedure as per your needs. First you need to loop to get records for each branch and store records in your second table...

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-syntax.html):

> Stored functions cannot be recursive.
>
> Recursion in stored procedures is permitted but disabled by default.

The [link provided by Meherzad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584013/how-to-find-the-hierarchy-path-for-a-tree-representation/15861254#15861254) as a comment shows how to scan a tree in a procedure. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439364/1446005) will give you hints as to how to emulate a function call with IN and OUT procedure parameters.